# how to send SMS within a loop in php

Tags: php, bulksms

I am trying to send multiple SMS using loop, but its not working. If there is only one row to fetch then it works.

**Code :**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $dealer_name = $row['dealer_name'];
    $dealer_contact_no = $row['contact_no'];

    $date = new DateTime($row['date']);
    $date = $date->format('d-M-y');
    $due_date = new DateTime($row['due_date']);
    $due_date = $due_date->format('d-M-y');

    //////////////////sms body 

    $msg .= 'Bill Payable-' . "%0A";
    $msg .= 'Bill No:' . $row['ref_no'] . "%0A";
    $msg .= 'Date:' . $date . "%0A";
    $msg .= 'Total Amt:' . $row['total_amount'] . "%0A";
    $msg .= 'Pending Amt:' . $row['pending_amount'] . "%0A";
    $msg .= 'Due Date:' . $due_date . "%0A";
    $msg .= 'Days:' . $row['days'] . "%0A";
    $msg .= '-' . $sender_name;

    $username = "abc";
    $password = "1922345418";
    $text = $msg;
    $phones = $dealer_contact_no;

    if (strlen($phones) == 10) {

        header('Location:http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&sendername=NETSMS&mobileno=' . $phones . '&message=' . $text . '');
    }
}
```

Comment: The `header()` is causing your code to kick out of the loop when it loads the other URL. Use `file_get_contents()` or a `CURL` request to grab those URLs instead.

Answer (score 4):

use php [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
file_get_contents('http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'&sendername=NETSMS&mobileno='.$phones.'&message='.$text.'');
}
```

header is exit your loop in first time call

Comment: You should explain why that line is working and why it's an error using `header`.

Comment: url is not run @Rahautos

Comment: <?php
$url = "";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $curl_scraped_page;
<?

Comment: not working.still the url is not running..its work only if fetch a single row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94429/discussion-between-ajay-krishna-dutta-and-rahautos).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $url = 'http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&sendername=NETSMS&mobileno=' . $phones . '&message=' . $text;

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

More examples of using cURL are given here: [Techniques for Mastering cURL](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/techniques-for-mastering-curl--net-8470)

Comment: within the loop or outside the loop?? not working inside the loop

Comment: @AjayKrishnaDutta within the loop

Comment: sms not send.. url is not run